# Is "site:" returning pages that would not otherwise be returned?

Tags: google-search, canonical-url, rel-canonical

Today I attempted a search on one of my websites as I thought I had a page about this or that and used the following in my search:

```
site:m2osw.com upload
```

I started looking through the results and could not find the very page I was looking for, but noticed that one of my website, we'll say "blah.m2osw.com", appeared in the results!

This was a big surprise to me because that site has had the correct canonical URL for a long time and it points to a different domain. Something like this:

```
<link rel="canonical"
      type="text/html"
      title="Home Page"
      href="https://exdox.com"/>
```

I was thinking that whenever you had a canonical it would tell Google to go look over there, but now I have a doubt and am thinking that maybe these canonical do not work cross domain? I thought I read somewhere that was the best way to have a test site anywhere I wanted and point the test site to the real site so Google indexes the real site and not the test site...

Do you know whether that canonical looks correct from `https://blah.m2osw.com` or whether I would have to add something else (i.e. the robots = NOINDEX for example...)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ```
> <meta rel="canonical"
>   type="text/html"
>   title="Home Page"
>   href="https://exdox.com"/>
> ```

This is incorrect. This should be a `link` element, not a `meta` element. For example:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="https://exdox.com">
```

The `type` and `title` attributes in this context are irrelevant.

> Is “site:” returning pages that would not otherwise be returned?

However, this is correct. The Google `site:` operator does indeed return URLs that would not ordinarily be returned in a normal Google search. The `rel="canonical"` link element doesn't necessarily prevent both pages from being *indexed*, but it *advises* Google that it should return the canonical page in the SERPs when possible. (The `site:` operator returns the pages that are *indexed*.) Whether Google follows this advice is, however, up to Google. If Google does not think (by its own analysis) that the declared "canonical" URL is not actually *canonical* (ie. sufficiently similar) then it could be ignored. From [Google Webmaster Central Blog - Handling legitimate cross-domain content duplication](https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2009/12/handling-legitimate-cross-domain.html)

> While the rel="canonical" link element is seen as a hint and not an absolute directive, we do try to follow it where possible.

**UPDATE:** If this is a "test site" then yes, it probably shouldn't be indexed at all and the `rel="canonical"` tag is mostly irrelevant. You should either `noindex` (robots `meta` tag or `X-Robots-Tag` HTTP response header) or block in `robots.txt` or restrict access in some other way (pwd, IP restriction, etc.).

Comment: Sorry about the typo, the site really has a `<link ...>` and not a `<meta ...>`. Also the title is nice to have on a browser like SeaMonkey.

Comment: So would you (strongly) recommend to have a NOINDEX on a test site? Because from what you're saying, without it, the test site could also end up being indexed, correct?

Comment: Ah, sorry missed that bit! If this is a "test site" then yes, it probably shouldn't be indexed at all and the `rel="canonical"` tag is pretty much irrelevant. You should either `noindex` (robots `meta` tag or `X-Robots-Tag` HTTP response header) or block in `robots.txt` or restrict access in some other way (pwd, IP restriction, etc.). I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 2):

> Do you know whether that canonical looks correct from https://blah.m2osw.com

This an example of really funny question ;)

To the point:

- canonical is just a recommendation. This means: Google will decide by its own, what to display as search result - canonicalized or canonical url
- the SERP Google builds for a site-query displays urls from a given domain, which are relevant to the meaningful query part. There could appear both of canonicalized and canonical urls - indeed they are both relevant to a given query, canonical - more, canonicalized - less.
- In the "normal", non-site query Google would abstain from displaying of canonicalized url because of less relevancy.

Comment: I suppose that means I should mark the test site with NOINDEX on all pages, correct? Because I really do not want to have search go to the wrong site!

Comment: yep. with noindex you are safe